# Getting invalid identifier ORA-00904 in Pivot block

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am getting invalid identifier in below query in pivot block, Please help in resolving this

```
select cif_id,
       to_char(tran_date,'MON-YYYY'),
       part_tran_type ,
       tran_amt
from CUSTOM.HTD_OCT_DEC19 H,
            tbaadm.gam 
pivot
(count(1),
 sum(tran_amt)
for **part_tran_type** in ('D','C'))
where h.tran_date ='24-DEC-2019' 
  and h.PSTD_FLG='Y' 
  and h.DEL_FLG='N' 
  and gam.cust_id='D46478329' 
  and h.cust_id=gam.cust_id 
  and rpt_code in ('20211','20212','20270','20271','20410','20420','20440',
                   '20501','20502','20504','60202');
```

Comment: Please format the code. Please read "How ask a Question section". Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not using `PIVOT` correctly. Try to use the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CIF_ID,
            TO_CHAR(TRAN_DATE, 'MON-YYYY') as TRAN_DATE,
            PART_TRAN_TYPE,
            TRAN_AMT
        FROM CUSTOM.HTD_OCT_DEC19 H, TBAADM.GAM
        WHERE
            H.TRAN_DATE = '24-DEC-2019'
            AND H.PSTD_FLG = 'Y'
            AND H.DEL_FLG = 'N'
            AND GAM.CUST_ID = 'D46478329'
            AND H.CUST_ID = GAM.CUST_ID
            AND RPT_CODE IN (
                '20211', '20212', '20270', '20271', '20410', '20420',
                '20440', '20501', '20502', '20504', '60202'
            )
    ) PIVOT (
        COUNT ( 1 ) AS CT, SUM ( TRAN_AMT ) AS SM
        FOR PART_TRAN_TYPE
        IN ( 'D', 'C' )
    )
```

Cheers!!

Comment: After executing the same, getting error ORA-00918 : column ambiugously defined

Answer (score 0):

Working now after changing the query as below :

`select * from 
    (
    select gam.cif_id,to_char(tran_date,'MON-YYYY'),h.part_tran_type 
    ,h.tran_amt 
    from CUSTOM.HTD_OCT_DEC19 H,tbaadm.gam 
    where h.tran_date ='24-DEC-2019' and h.PSTD_FLG='Y' and h.DEL_FLG='N'
    and gam.cif_id='D46478329' and h.cust_id=gam.cust_id and
    h.rpt_code in ('20211','20212','20270','20271','20410','20420','20440','20501','20502','20504','60202')
    ) 
    pivot 
    ( 
    count(1) as TXNCOUNT, sum(tran_amt) as TXNSUM 
    for part_tran_type in ('D' as DEBIT,'C' as CREDIT) 
    );`